# AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'select_by_value' selecting dropdown menu using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, html-select

I am trying to find menu prices for certain fast food restaurants from this [website](https://www.fastfoodmenuprices.com/baskin-robbins-prices) by different state. There is a dropdown menu where different states are the options. After I select a state (for example, California), I want to web scrape the different prices of their Ice Cream. However, I keep getting the same error message preventing me from getting the data. I think it works fine until going to the website, but it can't seem to select it by state. What do I need to do in order to:

1. Get selenium to accurately select a certain state (California)
2. Get the menu prices for just the "Ice Cream" category?

The Code is below:

```
!pip3 install selenium
!pip3 install webdriver-manager

from selenium import webdriver
import time 
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd

path = ("C:/path/to/chromedriver.exe")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path)
url = "https://www.fastfoodmenuprices.com/baskin-robbins-prices/"
driver.get(url)
select_state = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@class='tp-variation']").click
## select_state = driver.find_element_by_id("variation-tablepress-34")
select_state = driver.find_element_by_id("variation-tablepress-34")
select_state.select_by_value("MS4yOA==")
time.sleep(3)
```

The Error I get is:

```
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'select_by_value'
```

A photo of the code + error is below:

[image: Code_Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`select_by_value()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.select.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select.select_by_value) is a method from [**select**](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.select.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.select) class and to use it you have to use the [Select(webelement)](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.select.html#selenium.webdriver.support.select.Select) method.

---

### Solution

To select the option ***California*** you can use the following [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.fastfoodmenuprices.com/baskin-robbins-prices")
  Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//select[@class='tp-variation']")))).select_by_value("MS4yOA==")
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: California]